# Should I walk or run to my towel when naked and wet?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, everyday-life, evaporation, heat-conduction

This morning when I got out of the shower, I realised I had left my towel in the bedroom. Naked and wet I ran as fast as I could to get the towel. On my way back I didn't run, but rather walked, and it felt a lot less cold.

In this scenario, what is the optimal strategy to make this experience as tolerable as possible?

If I run fast, the air blows harder on my wet body, and evaporative cooling accelerates. If I walk very slowly, the air does not blow as hard on my body, but I am exposed to this reduced cooling effect for a longer period of time.

Is there are sweet spot that I could achieve here? Or are one of the extremes that actual best solution....ie just sprint.

Lets assume average values for air temperature and humidity. 21C and 40% relative humidity. Assume average bathroom to bedroom distance of 30' round trip. And to simplify, take human perception out of the mix and just optimise for surface skin temperature change.

Comment: I think this is a very complex problem to actually solve as it involves many factors which I find hard to reliably quantify in practice. The easiest parameter in play here is the rate of evaporation--which is still very complex because it is a non-equilibrium process and I don't think we have an explicit formula for it. Educate me if I am mistaken here. But the more complicated issue is how to relate the time spent at different cooling rates with the "human comfort". [...]

Comment: [...] The most practical answer I see is to assume that there is a threshold rate of cooling that we are comfortable with and to run at a speed so as to just saturate this bound. This makes (by virtue of the assumption) your cooling discomfort negligible while allowing you to terminate the process as quickly as possible.

Comment: The subjective aspect of this is too strong.  Is a bit of discomfort for a longer time better than more discomfort for less time?  Is there any way to quantify it?  (there's definitely a way to quantify heat; but it doesn't directly correlate to comfort)

Comment: [Related video](https://youtu.be/Re5fhBoF6sY) by Minute Physics

Comment: *just optimize for surface skin temperature change.* I don't think this is what you want. Humans are horrible thermometers. I think you mean to ask about heat transfer. And even then, you run into the issue that @JMac brings up that this doesn't necessarily correlate to comfort

Comment: Agree. But simplify in the name of getting somewhere, without bringing neurophysiology into consideration.

Comment: This makes it basically a homework problem with a fancy dressing on it.

Comment: It factors out the neurobiological component, to subsequently be solved at a later time, in a forum that is better for that type of question. You can spin that however you like.

Comment: If you want specific users to be notified of a comment, tag them in it using '@username'

Comment: I voted for reopening since this can easily be turned into a nice physics problem about reducing heat loss - the subjective part is beside the point.

Comment: @AndersSandberg If this can be turned into an on-topic question, it should be edited to reflect that. As it currently stands, the subjective part is an integral part of the question.

Comment: @AndersSandberg The current state of the question is more of a "solve this example heat transfer problem for me" which still isn't really on topic.

Comment: @ScottF I'm just pointing it out because such questions are also off topic.  See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The optimal strategy is to lie down and slither like a snake as this presents the least surface area for evaporative cooling. The exception is if you are bald in which case you should go feet first as there is no insulation gain from the hair on your head. If you are well bearded you also have the advantage of being able to look where you are going without loss of insulation and not end up mistaking the bedroom door for the font door.

Answer (score -3):

Before exiting the shower, **gradually** make the water as cold as you can tolerate without going into shock (avoid shivering, it's the first warning sign of hypothermia. The key is to do your best to relax your muscles and focus on your breathing). This causes the metabolism/heart-rate to increase in order to keep yourself warm. Once you step out of the shower, you'll feel like you just worked out a bit(juices pumping, endorphins flowing), and the air should feel warm on your body if you got the water cold enough. You should be good for that 30' walk in room temperature. Also, cold water is best for the skin, and the contraction/relaxing of the veins due to temperature fluctuation is good exercise for the vascular system. (not recommended if you have a heart condition).